# Open server fatal error out of memory

Tags: php, wordpress

My problem is:

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 2097152) (tried to allocate
>   8791446257187 bytes) in
>   C:\OpenServer\domains\whitecrossvet.local\wp-includes\functions.php on
>   line 5235

When I restart open server all becomes fine. But when I try to the load image to my wordpress site, which I'm developing, I get this problem.
I've tried to add:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

but this didn't help.

Comment: thi is a problem on my local machine

Comment: Does the size of the image influence this in any way?

Comment: did u put this just after <?php

Comment: Which kind of image do you upload? And which memory limit have you set in your `php.ini`?

Comment: yes, after <?php

Comment: I tried to add jpeg images

Comment: That's 8.79 TB the script is trying to allocate. Somewhere in your code is probably a big memory leak, or you are doing some insane recursion in there.

Comment: It's not my site, I just add some content. How can I find memory leak?

Comment: @Vladz first of all, show us code from `C:\OpenServer\domains\whitecrossvet.local\wp-includes\functions.php` near line 5235

Comment: function wp_is_stream( $path ) {
 $wrappers = stream_get_wrappers();

 /*5235 - start*/$wrappers_re = '(' . join('|', $wrappers) . ')'; /*5235 - end*/

 return preg_match( "!^$wrappers_re://!", $path ) === 1;
}